# Cannot delete the event issue

Tags: civicrm-event

When delete an event, I got bellow issue. Is there anyone knows how to fix it?
Thanks so much!

**We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.

Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.

Error type: Could not find a valid session key.**

Comment: pls spell out the exact steps you are taking - and compare it with the same steps on one of the demo or master sites - and report back. thx

Comment: also did you already check you have everything set up correctly in civicrm.settings.php and you have no problems such as those the warning is giving you

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using? Is it on wordpress, drupal, joomla, etc?